# function to empty array doesn't work inside then()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

the following is my code to add data from the form, when it will capture the value of this.error, the variable does not give any value. is there something wrong in my line of code?

```
saveContact: async function() {
  this.errors = [];
  if (this.name && this.phone) {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      phone: this.phone
    }).then(() => {
      this.name = ""
      this.phone = ""
      // This empty errors not working
      this.errors = [];
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.error = error
    });
  }
  if (!this.name) this.errors.push("name");
  if (!this.phone) this.errors.push("phone");
}
```

this.error is used first to accommodate errors that will occur, then if the addDoc() function in firebase is successful, then(), this.error = [] variable is emptied, so that the error disappears, but does not work.

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected behavior and what is happening ?

Comment: "not working" - how can you tell? you set `this.errors = []` at the top of the function, and do exactly the same thing in the `.then` ... how can you tell it's "not working"?

Comment: i want empty the 'name' value, but when i set this.name = "", this.errors give the error sign.  so i want empty array for this.error. but not working, whereas this.name its working

Comment: @bravo this.errors = [] on top is for clean all error every function running. and inside then inside then() is for clean error after i set this.name = '', but it's not working.

Comment: it IS working, but then you add to it at the bottom of the function! because this.name and this.phone will now be empty when that code runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you await the promise, and in the .then you are clearing `this.name` and `this.phone` - the code after the awaited promise will see `this.name` and `this.phone` as empty

added comments to explain in your code

```
saveContact: async function() {
  this.errors = []; // you clear the errors
  if (this.name && this.phone) {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      phone: this.phone
    }).then(() => {
      this.name = ""; // you empty the name
      this.phone = ""; // you empty the phone
      // This empty errors not working
      this.errors = []; // you clear the errors for no reason
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.error = error
    });
  }
  // here, name and phone will be empty, because you cleared them in the .then
  if (!this.name) this.errors.push("name");
  if (!this.phone) this.errors.push("phone");
}
```

One fix - last block of code in an `else`

```
saveContact: async function () {
    this.errors = [];
    if (this.name && this.phone) {
        this.loading = !this.loading;
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            phone: this.phone
        }).then(() => {
            this.name = "";
            this.phone = "";
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.error = error
        });
    } else {
        if (!this.name)
            this.errors.push("name");
        if (!this.phone)
            this.errors.push("phone");
    }
}
```

A better fix, and a better way to use async/await

```
saveContact: async function () {
    this.errors = []; // you clear the errors
    if (this.name && this.phone) {
        this.loading = !this.loading;
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
                phone: this.phone
            });
            this.name = "";
            this.phone = "";
        } catch {
            this.error = error;
        }
    } else {
        if (!this.name)
            this.errors.push("name");
        if (!this.phone)
            this.errors.push("phone");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kamal - well, that's why I posted code that should work - in fact, two pieces of code - the second showing how you *should* be using async/await

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store 'this' as some variable

Comment: why would the two previous this.xxx work and not that one? the answer doesn't make sense